# Angular FormGroup Error doesnt get displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the problem that my App doesnt diplay the errors. 
This is my html:

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating style="margin-left: 20px;">Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="username" formControlName="username" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.username" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="!registerForm.get('username').valid  && (registerForm.get('username').dirty)">
         <p style="color: white;" *ngIf="registerForm.get('username').hasError('taken')">funktioniert</p>
         <p style="color: white;" *ngIf="registerForm.get('username').hasError('min')">funktioniert</p>
         <p style="color: white;" *ngIf="registerForm.get('username').hasError('max')">funktioniert</p>
         <p style="color: white;" *ngIf="registerForm.get('username').hasError('latein')">funktioniert</p>
     </ion-item>
```

this is my ts:

```
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  this.registerForm = formBuilder.group({
          username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(15), Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'), UsernameValidator.checkUsername, Validators.required])],
          email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$'), EmailValidator.checkEmail, Validators.required])],
          password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.pattern('^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$'),PasswordValidator.checkPassword, Validators.required])]
      });
```

and this is my custom UsernameValidator:

```
export class UsernameValidator {
  static checkUsername(control: FormControl): any {
    var onlyLetters;

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if(control.value.toLowerCase() === "greg"){

          resolve({
            "taken": true
          });

        } else if (control.value.length < 3){
          resolve({
            "min": true
          });
        } else if (control.value.length > 8){
          resolve({
            "max": true
          });
        } else if (!(onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/.test(control.value))){
          resolve({
            "latein": true
          });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

this custom Validator should return the error Keys. In the html I want to check for the error keys and display the message if an error is true and the key got returned. But it doesnt seem to work. The Validation itselfe works. But ErrorMessages dont work.

Comment: can you reproduce this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your validator for checking if the username is taken, is an **async** validator. Async validators should be passed as the third argument.

so change your assignment of your `username` formcontrol to:

```ts
username: ['', [sync validators here], [UsernameValidator.checkUsername]]
```

** also `Validators.compose` is not needed.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zdce43?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**

---

as a non related issue, I would drop the `[(ngModel)]` and make use of the form control. You can set the initial value to your form control instead. If this arrives later, you can use `setValue()`:

```ts
this.registrationForm.setValue({
  username: this.registerCredentials.username
  // setting other possible values to your form controls
})
```

and remove the ngModel altogether. Having two bindings (`ngModel` and `FormControl`) can cause issues.